# Visual Studio Project - Automatically include externally created files?

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a nice solution to be able to automatically refresh/include externally created files in the asp.net application project?

The majority of the time I'm programming front end javascript in Sublime Text 2 editor. When integrating with the rest of the team I have to manually make sure that any new files i've created externally are included in the asp.net project.

Is there an automatic option to refresh the files in a particular folder or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

in the proj files you can edit the itemgroup includes so rather than just including individual files you can use glob patterns. such as

**app\****\*.js

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="app\**\*.js" />
    <Content Include="scripts\jquery.js" />
</ItemGroup>
```