# How to "include" automatically the appropriate files what bower is downloading in Visual Studio project?

Tags: visual-studio, bower

**Context:**

Bower is cool. It is downloading the configured things with all their dependencies to my wwwroot/lib folder.  However it is required to have those files also be the part of the Visual Studio solution for multiple reasons, just to name some: intellisense, Resharper, publish, (source control)

**Question:**

How to include the downloaded files to the VS solution automatically? (Note, this ***must*** be automated, as the upgrades/updates can contain new/removed files, so *if I had to check this after every time when bower looks for updates than I am just bought a productivity killer...*)

**Related Question:**

Bower downloads many things related to a dependency (I mean src, less, etc). This is cool, but obviously a big impact to include all to a Visual Studio regrding intellisense, or ***publish***. What is the best practice to overcome this? Is anybody cares about this, or is this concern only my overthinking?

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcards in the include statements in the csproj file - credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21907282/1405861).

I added:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="bower_components\**\*.js" />
    <Content Include="bower_components\**\*.css" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

to my csproj.